# Game Center Integration with My App

Tags: cocos2d-x, game-center

As i run my App ,everytime the Gamecenter popping up.i use below code in my AppDelegate.cpp .to connect with game center.My Question is i want to connect my App to Game center but it should not pop up when my Game Start.

```
  GKHWrapperCpp gkh;
  gkh.authenticateLocalPlayer();
```

Comment: If you are already authenticated it will no longer show the dialog, just a message that the player has signed in. Otherwise it will keep asking for Game Center credentials (Apple ID).

Comment: yea its showing the dialog "welcome back vineet".is there any way that it should not show the dialog?